# How to open a new HTML page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, ibm-mobilefirst

So, I am using IBM Worklight where I have the main file called `file1.html` and then I created another html file called `file2.html`.

I am trying to open file2 but no luck so far. I tried following pieces of code:

1. `$(this).load("file2.html");`
2. `$("div1").load("file2.html"); //div1 is the id for outer div of file1`
3. `WL.App.openUrl("file2.html");`
4. `window.openURL("file2.html");`

And none of these worked! Any suggestions?

Comment: tried `window.location.href = 'file2.html'` ?

Comment: If you're selecting by `id` then you need to preface the `id` with a `#`: `$('#div1').load(/* ...other stuff... */);`

Comment: Open how? In a new separate browser tab? Or in the same tab (replacing the current page)? Or as a pop-up window? Or into an IFRAME element in the current page? Or just dump the contents of the second page into the current page? You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, the .load() function is the correct function you are after;

But you are missing the `#` from the div1 id selector in the example 2)

This should work:

```
$("#div1").load("file2.html");
```

Comment: okay this works just fine $.get("file2.html", function (deals) {
      $('#wrapper').html(deals);
      
      getDeals(deals);...but now how can i get access to deals in file2..file2 has different jQuery file to it?? Plzz help
   });

Comment: or do `$("body").load("index.html")` to render a new page

Comment: This opens the page inside the modal (if you are inside a modal window).

Answer (score 48):

use `window.open("file2.html");` to open on new window,

or use `window.location.href = "file2.html"` to open on same window.

Answer (score 7):

Use [window.open("file2.html");](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

**Syntax**

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

**Return value and parameters**

```
windowObjectReference
```

A reference to the newly created window. If the call failed, it will be null. The reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new window provided it complies with Same origin policy security requirements.

```
strUrl
```

The URL to be loaded in the newly opened window.  `strUrl` can be an HTML document on the web, image file or any resource supported by the browser.

```
strWindowName
```

A string name for the new window. The name can be used as the target of links and forms using the target attribute of an `<a>` or `<form>` element. The name should not contain any blank space. Note that `strWindowName` does not specify the title of the new window.

```
strWindowFeatures
```

Optional parameter listing the features (size, position, scrollbars, etc.) of the new window. The string must not contain any blank space, each feature name and value must be separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
<code>
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
</code>
```

Comment: Or if you want to redirect the user to the other page use this

window.location.href = "file2.html";