# How to open a new page in jQuery Mobile from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my html form.When i enter values in the `textfield`, a background operation is performed and data is sent to the server.But since this button already has an event (submit), how do i open a new page once that background operation is completed?

This is the button.

```
<a href="#" id="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true"> Submit</a>
```

and in my javascript i have this function

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("#submit").bind('click', function(event){
    doSomeBackgroundStuff();

});
```

This is happening from `Page A`, i want `Page B` to open when `doSomeBackgroundStuff()` finishes.

Comment: You could use a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

> since this button already has an event (submit)

Use preventDefault or return false:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("#submit").bind('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //or just use : return false; at last  
     doSomeBackgroundStuff();

});
```

Comment: But how does this tell `javascript` to open `Page B`?

Comment: your event is throwing to open Page A from the default event funcitons as you said, so now you are trying to open Page B which would opened and prevent to do some other task means will not open Page A

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.The `submit` button does not open `Page A`, it is a button in that page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

First, working with what you have already, You could use a callback function for your bind event, and add window.open to load the new page, and simply pass in a url, or hardcode it.

Your jquery would look something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("#submit").bind('click', function(event){
    //fire AJAX request
    doSomeBackgroundStuff();

},function(){//call back function
window.open('http://www.yourURL.com');
});//end bind

});//end doc ready
```

Here is further reading on window.open - [How to open a new HTML page using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983869/how-to-open-a-new-html-page-from-jquery)

A second option is to use AJAX. You would setup an AJAX request for the new page, and use $.ajaxSend and $.ajaxComplete to fire functions before and after the request.

Your jquery would look something like:

```
//on button click
$('#submit').click(function(){
   doSomeBackgroundStuff();
});

//ajax start handler
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    //do stuff before AJAX request
});

//ajax complete
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  //do stuff after AJAX request

});
```

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216493/javascript-jquery-page-change-event-on-mobile-browsers/23378657#23378657) with a similar solution.

[Global AJAX handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am trying to open a new page in my app.`Page B` isn't a web address, but a page on my app.However, using your suggestion i did something like `window.open("#page_b_id);`. This opens `Page B` in a new window (not desired outcome) and `doSomeBackgroundStuff()` doesn't execute.

Comment: sounds to me like you need an ajax solution then. you could use the ajax complete method to doSomeBackgroundStuff. My answer to the following question may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216493/javascript-jquery-page-change-event-on-mobile-browsers/23378657#23378657