# How to redirect to same page but to a different div/view in IBM Worklight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibm-mobilefirst

Initially Testing by user name only not the password.
After successful login it gives login successful alert but cannot redirect to particular div or view(from mobile navigation IBM Worklight) on the same html page(YummyjQueryMobile145.html).

Tested codes like:

```
//#login > login button id
//#home > redirected div/view id

$(function(){
$("#login").click(function(){
                $("#home").load("YummyjQueryMobile145.html", function(){
                    alert("loaded!");
                });
            });
});
```

JS file

```
function Login()
    {
        //alert("Login");
        var invocationLogin={
                adapter:"SQL_ADAPTER_Yummy",
                procedure:"procedureLogin",
                parameters:[]
               };

    var optionsLogin={
            onSuccess:succLogin,
            onFailure:failLogin
            };
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationLogin,optionsLogin);
    }

    function succLogin(result)
    {
        //alert("succLogin");
        var LUname=$("#LUname").val();
        var LPass=$("#LPass").val();
        var flag=0;
        var n;

        var i,
        resultSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet;
        //alert(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
        namesArray = [];

        for (i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++)
        {
        namesArray[i] = resultSet[i].NAME;
        }

        //alert (JSON.stringify(namesArray));

        for (i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++)
        {
            n = LUname.localeCompare(namesArray[i]);
            if(n==0)
            flag=1;
        }

        if(flag==1)
            {
            alert("Login Successful");
            //Here the Redirect code/same html page to a particular div or view
           //clicking login button if success then redirect to home div/view

            }
        else
            alert("Try Again!!!");

    }

    function failLogin(result)
    {
         alert(result+"try again Login");
    }
```

HTML

```
....
<div class="bg" id="LogIn" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true"
data-back-btn-text="Home" data-theme="b">
....
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" data-theme="a" onclick="Login()">Log In</a>
....
<div class="bg" data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.location like :

```
window.location='same_page_url#id_of_the_div';
```

Comment: still not working $(window).load("YummyjQueryMobile145.html#home");

Comment: @sphakrrokrSubhrojit Edited the answer ..check now .. is it working for you ?

Comment: if(flag==1)
     {
     alert("Login Successful");
     
     $(window).load("#home");
    
     }

Comment: Thanks a lot.BTW I searched on this topic there are many answers/solutions so why others getting the solution but not mine?Even I also tried this > $("#home").load("YummyjQueryMobile145.html");  but still not success.Where to learn on these topics?What is the perfect online site other than w3schools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983869/how-to-open-a-new-html-page-using-jquery

Comment: Many sites are there ..just google about it buddy .. there is a tutorial for jquery api https://api.jquery.com/ here .. you can go through it .. anyways ..if the answer helped ..please accept .. thanks